# Casting Custom Swift Error Back from Kotlin in KMM?

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, error-handling, kotlin-multiplatform

I am working on a Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) project and I have a custom error defined in Swift like so:

```
enum MyError: Error {
    case runtimeError(String)
}
```

I have a method in Swift which throws this error:

```
func someThrowableMethod() throws -> {
   throw MyError.runtimeError("my custom error")
}
```

On the Kotlin side, I catch this exception and try to pass it back to some Swift code:

```
try {
   someThrowableMethod()
} catch(err: Throwable) {
   passToIosCode(err)
}
```

Now back in Swift, I have the following method:

```
func passToIosCode(err: KotlinThrowable) {
   err.asError() // how to extract MyError? 
}
```

I am looking for a way to cast back the caught `MyError` in Kotlin to Swift. How can I achieve this? Is there a mechanism to unwrap or cast the original Swift error back from Kotlin in a KMM project?

Comment: Can Kotlin even catch the Swift error? As far as I can see from the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html#errors-and-exceptions), this is not implemented yet. "Swift/Objective-C error-throwing methods aren't imported to Kotlin as exception-throwing."

Comment: It can catch as `NSError`. You can try it able to catch.

Comment: [This might be helpful.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45127/KMM-hard-to-pass-an-error-to-Kotlin-code-from-implementation-of-Kotlin-method-in-Swift-code)

Comment: @Sweeper thanks this is helped! It looks weird with this re-throw mechanism, but it works.